# Python reversed in C++11

Tags: python, c++, c++11, iterator, reinventing-the-wheel

I was playing with some of the wonderful new C++11 features and tried to reimplement a function `reversed` that would behave just like the one in Python to allow reverse iteration on bidirectional iterables.

And to clarify since I'm been told that I was unclear, that `reverse` function would be used in range-based for loops. Also, I define an iterator as whatever satisfies the functions `std::begin` and `std::end` (`ForwardIterator` concept). I don't think I've got to explain what a bidirectional iterator is... :D

Here's my code:

```
template<typename BidirectionalIterable>
class ReversedObject
{
    private:

        BidirectionalIterable& _iter;

        ReversedObject(BidirectionalIterable&& iter):
            _iter(iter)
        {}

    public:

        using value_type = typename std::decay<decltype(*std::begin(_iter))>::type;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using reference = value_type&;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using iterator = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(itertools::rbegin(_iter))>::type;
        using const_iterator = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(itertools::rbegin(_iter))>::type;
        using reverse_iterator = decltype(std::begin(_iter));
        using const_reverse_iterator = decltype(std::begin(_iter));
        using iterator_category = typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::iterator_category;

        // Iterator functions
        auto begin() -> iterator
            { return itertools::rbegin(_iter); }
        auto begin() const -> const_iterator
            { return itertools::rbegin(_iter); }
        auto cbegin() const -> const_iterator
            { return itertools::rbegin(_iter); }
        auto end() -> iterator
            { return itertools::rend(_iter); }
        auto end() const -> const_iterator
            { return itertools::rend(_iter); }
        auto cend() const -> const_iterator
            { return itertools::rend(_iter); }

        // Reverse iterator functions
        auto rbegin() -> reverse_iterator
            { return std::begin(_iter); }
        auto rbegin() const -> const_reverse_iterator
            { return std::begin(_iter); }
        auto crbegin() const -> const_reverse_iterator
            { return std::begin(_iter); }
        auto rend() -> reverse_iterator
            { return std::end(_iter); }
        auto rend() const -> const_reverse_iterator
            { return std::end(_iter); }
        auto crend() const -> const_reverse_iterator
            { return std::end(_iter); }

    friend auto reversed<>(BidirectionalIterable&& iter)
        -> ReversedObject<BidirectionalIterable>;
};

template<typename BidirectionalIterable>
inline auto reversed(BidirectionalIterable&& iter)
    -> ReversedObject<BidirectionalIterable>
{
    return { std::forward<BidirectionalIterable>(iter) };
}
```

---

In order for that code to work, I had to write the global functions `rbegin` and `rend` with specializations for fixed-size arrays. Since c++14, these functions can be replaced by the standard functions [`std::rbegin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin) and [`std::rend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rend).

```
template<typename T>
auto rbegin(T& iter)
    -> decltype(iter.rbegin())
{
    return iter.rbegin();
}

template<typename T>
auto rbegin(const T& iter)
    -> decltype(iter.crbegin())
{
    return iter.crbegin();
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
auto rbegin(T (&array)[N])
    -> std::reverse_iterator<T*>
{
    return std::reverse_iterator<T*>(std::end(array));
}

template<typename T>
auto rend(T& iter)
    -> decltype(iter.rend())
{
    return iter.rend();
}

template<typename T>
auto rend(const T& iter)
    -> decltype(iter.crend())
{
    return iter.crend();
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
auto rend(T (&array)[N])
    -> std::reverse_iterator<T*>
{
    return std::reverse_iterator<T*>(std::begin(array));;
}
```

Is there any way I could improve this construct's design? :)

---

Example of use case of the class:

```
int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::vector<int> vec = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 123 };

// Reverse iteration with fixed-size arrays
for (int i: reversed(array))
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

// Reverse iteration with standard containers
for (auto& i: reversed(vec))
{
    i *= 5;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

// Reverse iteration with initilizer_list
for (const char* str:  reversed({"one", "two", "three"}))
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is an 'iterable' a container usually? Everywhere you use `iter` is tremendously confusing because that usually means *iterator* not *iterable* (container)

Comment: What's the point of this class? If you plug in `std::vector` for instance you just get a subset of the functionality that `std::vector` gave you in the first place? Is it for pseudo-*concepts* purposes? But if so, maybe accepting a `begin` and `end` and using SFINAE and `iterator_traits` to disallow the method unless the iterator is bidirectional is a better option

Comment: @Dave I expressed the purpose in the introduction: find a simple way to use reverse iteration on iterables on C++11 foreach loops. Nothing to do with concepts or anything. I just liked how simple it was in Python and tried to mimick it in C++11.

Comment: You never mentioned foreach loops. I don't know how it is in Python. I also don't entirely know what you mean by iterable. I mostly get it. See my first comment. Now that you have mentioned C++11 range based for loops (presumably what you were referring to), check out the proposal for a `std::range`. It entirely covers your use case here. I would link it, but I don't feel particularly inclined to help *too* much after that response...

Comment: @Dave Well, that's true that I may have forgotten to mention the foreach loop, but `reversed` was introduced in Python mostly for that loop (see PEP 322). I would have defined an iterable object by whichever object that could be used with the functions `std::begin` and `std::end` (at least forward iterable that is, see `iterator_concept` for more details). I already knew about `std::range`, but it's still not in the standard and I would simply like for my class to be usesable with the components that already exist in N3485^^

Comment: So implement std::range yourself or download the library being developed by the authors. It's more useful than this.

Comment: Also: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/reversed.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall I like this helper. Most potential complaints are due to evaluating how well it would handle something it wasn't intended to support. Here are some of my thoughts from examining its implementation.

This code goes out of its way to define a lot of names for types that are not used directly by the consuming code (`value_type`, `difference_type`, etc.), nor by my understanding of the mechanisms of range-based for. Yet it doesn't offer an explicit overload for `std::begin` and friends.

There's no specialization for `reversed(reversed(container))`. While this is probably fine because it's unlikely to come up, and likely to be inlined down to the original container, I almost expected to see something like this explicitly cover this case:

```
template<typename BidirectionalIterable>
inline auto reversed(ReversedObject<BidirectionalIterable>&& iter)
    -> BidirectionalIterable
{
    return { std::forward<BidirectionalIterable>(iter._iter) };
}
```

As other commenters have said, calling it `iter` in a c++ world is a bit confusing. Then again calling it `iter` in python would be stomping on the builtin. So I would recommend renaming it `iterable` or `container`.

It would be interesting to try to reveal more of the underlying container per Dave's comment about a subset of a vector's functionality. If this is only ever used directly in a range-based for loop, that's not too important. But if someone starts saving reversed containers (it could be interesting to have a vector that effectively has a `push_front` instead of a `push_back`), it would become frustrating to lack other methods. Could an approach that derives from the reversed container do the trick? Hmm, probably not; this would typically result in copying the full data structure, `operator[]` would have to be adjusted, and `data()` would fall apart. But that thought about copying brings up another point. The name `ReversedObject` is misleading; it's more like a `ReversedView`.

I do like the fact that trying to reverse something that doesn't have reverse iterators will fail at compile time, even if its iterators are not invoked. The following gave me clear compilation errors:

```
struct NonReversible {};
auto a = NonReversible();
auto b = reversed(a); // clear errors pointing here
```

I don't like the `itertools` items as much. If we could just jump ahead to C++14, that'd be fine. Outside that, my first inclination is that I'd rather see this specialization done as a partial specialization of the `ReversedObject` class. But it's more reusable the way you did it, and the way C++ is going, so it's hard to justify my reaction.

Thanks for the interesting code to review. It makes me want to try to write a `zip` for range-based for loops. (Even though it's [already been done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511035/sequence-zip-function-for-c11) too.)

Comment: At first, it was only intended to be used in a range-based `for` loop. Therefore, I think you're right, I can delete `value_type` and its friends. I will also rename `iter` to `iterable`, you're right :)
I'll also delete the `itertools` stuff and use C++14, I did not realize that I left that in place...

Comment: fwiw, I disagree with explicitly covering `reversed(reversed(t))` - `reversed` should almost always produce a zero overhead layer (totally optimized out out of existence) so it doesn't matter. Plus, who would write that?